# Auto login on freemember registration

Tags: freemember

Quick question - can the FreeMember register tag login the user automatically? Apologies if I've missed anything in the docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. You just need to make sure this is enabled in the ExpressionEngine settings, which FreeMember inherits.

Go to the ExpressionEngine Control Panel > Members > Preferences, and set *Require Member Account Activation?* to *No activation required*.

Answer (score 0):

I need to leave member activation by email enabled for a certain member group but bypass it and auto-login the user for others after registration, is there some way to do this either by passing the registered member ID to the subsequent page where a 'log-in' plug can be used (dangerous!) or by performing the log-in by means of an extension which fires after registration in Freemember is complete?

I think I saw the idea of 'disabling' require member account activation' elsewhere by setting the variable before the register process starts but I don't recall exactly where this was.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

No, it can't.

There's a third-party add-on called Simple Registration
http://wedoaddons.com/addon/simple-registration/documentation
that will do this, though.

TTFN

Travis